# multiple values for same tag category in vsphere with terraform

Tags: terraform, tags, virtual-machine, vsphere

Im using the terraform module https://github.com/Terraform-VMWare-Modules/terraform-vsphere-vm
In Vcenter i configured multiple tags for same category "applications"
So a vm can have a tag like docker / nginx / etc..

When i use the tags variables on module it doesnt show them all but just take the last one on the common category

```
tags = {
"applications" = "docker"
"applications" = "nginx"
"test" = "test1"
}
```

vsphere will just keep "nginx" and "test1" but ignore "docker"
As far as i understand there is a mapping of the list of tags set to a list of id in order to assign the tags to the vm.

So when it find applications category it consider that there is just 1 element and not 2. I tried to make lists as well but i dont succeed to make it works

on module

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    tags                    = var.tag_ids != null ? var.tag_ids : data.vsphere_tag.tag[*].id
....
}
```

```
data "vsphere_tag_category" "category" {
  count      = var.tags != null ? length(var.tags) : 0
  name       = keys(var.tags)[count.index]
  depends_on = [var.tag_depends_on]
}

data "vsphere_tag" "tag" {                                                                                                                                                                                          
  count       = var.tags != null ? length(var.tags) : 0
  name        = var.tags[keys(var.tags)[count.index]]
  category_id = data.vsphere_tag_category.category[count.index].id
  depends_on  = [var.tag_depends_on]
}
```

Help will be more than welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maps/hashes/dictionaries in any language do not allow duplicate key assignments. During resolution, this would either throw an error or resolve to one of the values (your observed behavior) depending upon the language. You would need to restructure the `object` to only contain one key `applications`:

```
tags = {
  "applications" = "docker nginx"
  "test"         = "test1"
}
```

or:

```
tags = {
  "applications" = "docker, nginx"
  "test"         = "test1"
}
```

etc. Note that the value requires a String type, so you could not i.e.:

```
tags = {
  "applications" = ["docker", "nginx"] # throws type error from provider schema validation
  "test"         = "test1"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it already tried your both solution and terraform doesnt see 2 elements that way, i actually need to pass tru a map of list like this "applications" = ["docker", "nginx"] and use flattern function but i don;t see how to make it :/